# What is wrong with this jQuery element innerHTML statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML page, I have a span:

```
<span id="nlbNode">...</span>
```

In my $(document).ready function, I have the following.

```
if (document.getElementById("nlbNode")) {
    document.getElementById("nlbNode").innerHTML = "A";
}
```

And this works fine, however if I do this:

```
if (document.getElementById("nlbNode")) {
    $("#nlbNode").innerHTML = "A";
}
```

It does not work.  It does nothing.  Not even an error.  The span's innerHTML remains unchanged.

So, why doesn't it work?

Comment: in jquery use .html()   $("#nlbNode").html("A");

Comment: In jQuery `$()` function doesn't return a DOM element like it does in some other libraries.

Comment: I do not see innerHTML listed in the docs: https://api.jquery.com/

Comment: squint.  I wish I could upvote comments!  ;-)

Comment: For fun, I should mention that the other source I was looking at that made me feel my syntax was OK was "Experts Exhange".  That's why I prefer StackOverflow!  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's Node element doesn't have a `innerHTML` method. If you want to use `innerHTML` you can either retrieve the element's DOM counterpart via [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$("#nlbNode").get(0).innerHTML = "A"
```

Or use jQuery's [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method:

```
$("#nlbNode").text("A");
```

Comment: or `$("#nlbNode").html("A");`

Comment: Apparently, I have to wait for enough minutes to pass before I can "accept an answer".  But I will, Griffith.  Thanks.

Comment: Both Griffith, and Arnav proposed solutions that showed me what was wrong.  Basically, I was using incorrect syntax.  I will have to give the answer to Griffith, as he answered first, however I would like to point out that I am actually going to implement +Pekka's answer as I prefer "html" to "text" because it sticks closer to the html DOM naming convention.  Thanks, guys.

Comment: Thanks, anonymous internet user, for the downvote just seconds AFTER the question has been answered.  I hope you aren't the "other guy" who is upset I didn't select your answer.  Especially after I thanked both of you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming, that since you said you included

```
$(document).ready(function() {};
```

that you have jQuery included somewhere. This means you can `.html()` to get the result.For example:

```
if (document.getElementById("nlbNode")) {
   $("#nlbNode").html("A");
}
```

**EDIT**
Sorry, I forgot to include the rest of the answer. You probably know this by now, although I will say it again. jQuery does not have an innerHtml method in its node since it doesn't return the DOM element like other frameworks.